# How to pass AsyncResponse Object to Resteasy Proxy

Tags: java, resteasy

I recently found out about the Resteasy proxy framework for REST-Calls. this seems to be much more readable and relyable than regular calls, so i gave it a shot. I soon came to a point that i could not solve:

Interface :

```
@Path("/")
public interface ProcessingInterface {
   @POST
   @Path("/{uuid}")
   void startProcessing(@PathParam("uuid") String uuid, 
                        @Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse);
}
```

And corresponding implementation method header without annotations(correct?):

```
@Override
public void startProcessing(String uuid, AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
  ...
}
```

The service worked before, so i know that in general the annotation @Suspended is used correctly.

My problem now is, if i want to proxy this interface

```
ProccessingInterface proccessingInterface =  target.proxy(ProccessingInterface.class);
```

and try to execute the POST to my service, i need to pass the @Suspended AsyncResponse - which is abstract, as is the RestEasyAsyncrounousResponse implementation.

How is this intended to be done?